# Jenkins Symbolic Link Script Syntax

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a symbolic link in my JenkinsFile script for Windows but cannot get it to work as I am not sure about the syntax. Given below is the snippet I have currently in my script file:

```
node {
    stage('Setup SymLink') {
        def workspace = pwd()
        dir("c:\\work") {
            bat 'if exist "config" rmdir /s /q "config"'
            bat 'mklink /D config "${workspace}@script\\config"'            
        }
    }
}
```

The link target seems to have been created as:

**C:\work\${workspace}@script\config**

It doesn't seem to be resolving to the correct **${workspace}\config** location and also prefixing with **C:\work**

Any idea of getting the correct syntax in Jenkins for this scenario? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Single-quoted strings in groovy don't support interpolation. You need to use one of the [string literal syntaxes](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_summary_table) that does. For example:

```
node {
    stage('Setup SymLink') {
        def workspace = pwd()
        dir("c:\\work") {
            bat 'if exist "config" rmdir /s /q "config"'
            bat "mklink /D config \"${workspace}@script\\config\""            
        }
    }
}
```